# stacked bar chart - independent bar height from internal labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jqplot

[image]I am currently using the 3th example of bar stacked chart of jqplot from their page. See here http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php. Currently each bar height is the sum of all internal labels inside. However, what I would like is to adjust the height of the bar manually according to a different scale from its internal labels. For example, if the bar has 3 different labels and their sum is 1 + 2 + 3 = 6. However, the actual bar height containing these labels should represent 15 on the actual bar chart.

Is that possible in jqplot or do you know any js library which can do something like that?

Comment: The values of 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 you want represented by a total height of all three series = 15? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I want the bar height to be independent from the actual labels inside the bar since I will use different scales for the bar height and the labels

Comment: The labels in the bar (at least in highcharts) is the value of that bar. The sum of the labels = the total value of the stack. The total bar height = sum of the individual bars stacked. You can modify the text of the dataLabel in highcharts to be whatever you want as well as modify the yAxis labels. But, your point values dictate the size of the bar. It would be helpful to see a sample output of what you want with the data you are feeding into the chart.

Comment: I've added an example of what I am trying to achieve. The actual size of each bar is defined by one scale. The internal labels are determined by other scales. So the sum of the label points != the size of the bars since they are simply different scales.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. In highcharts this is doable via the `dataLabels.formatter` I have no idea how this is done in jqplot.

Comment: I know that highcharts is paid. Do you know another library with this functionality which is free? Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68233/discussion-between-user3793865-and-wergeld).

Comment: Quick search of the docs on jqplot leads me to: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pointLabels-js.html#$.jqplot.PointLabels.labelsFromSeries. So you can specify a label explicitly via [x, y, LABEL].